# How to set props into const X = useContext()

Tags: reactjs, react-props, use-context

*Using ReactJS*

I am wondering, how I can pass props into `const { answerSetter } = useContext( AnswerSetterContext );`
The reason I want to do this is beacause I get error, that X is not a function and passsing props there should fix it.
My code: `export const AnswerSetterContext = createContext(null);`

```
<AnswerSetterContext.Provider value={answerSetter}>
         <SearchBar key="SearchBar" placeholder="Type something" data={data} />
      </AnswerSetterContext.Provider> 

const { answerSetter } = useContext(AnswerSetterContext);

const handleOptionClick = event => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
```

answerSetter is not a function ==>       answerSetter(selectedValue);
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object into `AnswerSetterContext.Provider` (please notice the extra pair of curly brackets `{}` around `answerSetter` when I pass it into `value` prop):

```js
<AnswerSetterContext.Provider value={{answerSetter}}>
    <SearchBar key="SearchBar" placeholder="Type something" data={data} />
</AnswerSetterContext.Provider> 

const { answerSetter } = useContext(AnswerSetterContext);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it would be something silly like that :).